# What does Tosfos 46B mean by "for the sake of the sukkah"?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, sukkah, shmini-atzeres, tosfot, masechet-sukkah

Tosafos Sukkah 46B talks of the rabbis making a decree that one cannot eat the esrog.

Tosfos says that in Eretz Yisrael, the decree is not made on account of the sukkah. Whereas in the diaspora, the decree is made on account of the sukkah.

(i.e. and it doesn't say for the sake of sukkot, it says for the sake of the sukkah)

The question is, what does for the sake of the sukkah, or on account of the sukkah, mean?

The Gemara ([Succah 46b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=46b&format=text) towards the bottom ([pdf](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=46b&format=pdf))) is discussing the permissibility of eating an etrog that has been used for its mitzvah.

[Here's the Tosafot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrMHG.png).

Here's a translation:  provided by Seth.

> *The 8th (day of Sukkot, which is) a doubtful 7th (day of Sukkot), it is forbidden (to eat the etrog).* In the Land of Israel, which
>   lacks a doubt, it is not decreed
>   for the sake of the sukkah, but in Babylonia,
>   which has a doubt, even though one does not bless on it, it is decreed for the sake of the sukkah.

Tosafot finishes by saying: (translation from Seth)

> But the 9th (which is) a doubtful 8th (day, ie., Shmini Atzeret), it is not
>   decreed for the sake of the sukkah.

Also, a useful factoid, somebody mentioned that the ritva had a different girsa that rejected this tosfos.

Comment: http://www.tosfosinenglish.com/asp/ or http://www.tosfos.com/

Comment: [−1.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9553308#9553308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attempt at an answer

Tosfos is commenting on what Abaye says, so one must look at what he says.

Note- it may be a bit more complex than this. like tosfos may be commenting on rashi, and tosfos and rashi may differ. With tosfos taking Abaye's position and Rashi taking Levi's position(as fred might suggest). But i'm  answering based on what I have translations of.

Here is a quote from the gemara of 46B, from Abaye.

Below they are talking about Israel. The Esrog is permitted to be eaten on the 8th day.

> Said R. Papa to Abaye, What, according to R. Johanan, is the essential
>   difference between the Sukkah and the ethrog?24 — The other answered
>   him, The Sukkah which is fit to be used at twilight [after the seventh
>   day], for were he perchance to have a meal at that time he would be
>   expected to sit therein and eat there, is set aside for its ritual
>   purpose during the twilight, and since it is set aside during
>   twilight, it is also set aside for the whole of the eighth day; the
>   ethrog, however, which is not suitable during twilight,25 is not set
>   aside for its ritual purpose during twilight, hence it is not set
>   aside for the purpose for the whole of the eighth day.

Below Abaye is talking about the Diaspora

> And as for us, who42 keep two days [of the Festival] how are we to
>   proceed?43 — Abaye replied, On the eighth day which may be the
>   seventh,it44 is forbidden;45 on the ninth day which may be the eighth,
>   it is permitted.

By understanding what Abaye is saying, we can make sense of the Tosfos provided by Seth.

The only reason why, in Israel, the Sukkah is forbidden to be used as fuel on the 8th day, is because it is used at twilight which is into the beginning of the 8th day, and gets set aside for the whole of the 8th day. Whereas the Esrog is not being ritually used at the beginning of the 8th day, and therefore is not set aside for the whole of the 8th day.

In the diaspora, the 8th may be the 7th, and so the esrog is ritually used on the 7th and thus set aside for the whole of the 7th. So on the 8th that may be the 7th, you don't want to be eating the esrog.  (One could say, but the Esrog isn't ritually used on the 8th, so why should it be set aside on the 8th. I suppose it's still set aside on the 8th, as one can set it aside without offending/detracting from Shmini Atzeret, and thus one still can't eat it on the 8th - that would offend/detract from the sfak Succot).

So when Tosfos says "on account of the succah" it means sitting in the succah at twilight.

The Tosfos still doesn't entirely make sense, because Abaye explains perfectly well that he decrees that we can eat the esrog on the 8th day in Israel, and we can't eat the esrog on the 8th day in the diaspora, and it's nothing to do with sitting in the succah at twilight.

Abaye only brings up about sitting in the succah at twilight, to show why in Israel on the 8th day it's forbidden to use the succah as fuel, even though it's permitted to eat the esrog. It's strange that Tosfos makes a connection.

The Tosfos is only explaining Abaye's ruling, and somebody commented that the Ritva has a different Girsa that rejected this Tosfos.

One answer suggested that "on account of sukkah" meant that if we eat the esrog we may accidentally eat a succah decoration, but that is very speculative, and reading a lot in.

Since this Tosfos is just trying to explain Abaye's position, and Abaye's position is I'd say "on account of sukkah" means what Abaye was talking about - sitting in the sukkah at twilight. There are some potentially useful comments on that answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the text of that Tosafos (s.v. שמיני ספק שביעי אסור):

> שמיני ספק שביעי אסור'. בארץ ישראל דליכא ספיק' לא גזור אטו סוכה אבל בבבל דאיכא ספיקא אע"ג דלא מברך ביה גזור אטו סוכה אבל תשיעי ספק שמיני לא גזור אתרוג אטו סוכה

Translation (my clarifications are in brackets):

> **Excerpt from the Talmud**: "On the eighth, which might actually be the seventh, it is forbidden [eat the *esrog*, since it is *muktza*]."
>
> **Commentary**: In Israel, where there is no doubt as to the correct day, the Rabbis did not decree to forbid eating the *esrog* on account of the *sukka* [which remains *muktza* on the eighth day due to the fact that people might continue their meals in the *sukka* into *bein hash'mashos* (see earlier on 46b)].
>
> In Babylonia, however, where there is a doubt as to the correct day, even though we don't go so far as to make a blessing [upon eating in the *sukka*], the Rabbis decreed to forbid [eating the *esrog*] on account of the *sukka* [which is not simply *muktza* due to the fact that people might continue their meals into the eighth day, but is rather *muktza* for the stronger reason that the eighth day is considered a possible seventh day and people therefore eat in the *sukka* on the eighth day to fulfill a *mitzva misafeik*].
>
> Nevertheless, on the ninth day which [in Babylonia] might actually be the eighth day, the Rabbi's did not decree to forbid [eating the *esrog*] on account of the *sukka* [which, similar to Israel on the eighth day, is only *muktza* due to the fact that people might continue their meals in the *sukka* into *bein hash'mashos* of the next day].

See *Sukka* (10a-b), which describes that the fruits which are decoratively hung in the *sukka* and which become *muktza* like the *sukka* since those decorations become an ancillary part of the it. Apparently, the *Ba'alei HaTosafos* interpret the Talmud as being concerned that if people are allowed to eat *esrogim*, they might also eat the *sukka* decorations. When the only reason that the decorations are *muktza* is מיגו דאתקצאי לבין השמשות אתקצאי לכולי יומא דשמיני, however, the Rabbis did not go out of their way to make a special decree forbidding eating *esrogim*.

Note that Tosafos disagree with Rashi's<sup>1</sup> apparent position (46b, s.v. אתרוג אפילו בשמיני אסורה) that the reason to forbid eating the *esrog* is because the rule of מיגו דאתקצאי לבין השמשות אתקצאי לכולי יומא דשמיני directly applies to *esrogim*. The basis for rejecting Rashi's position is described in an earlier Tosafos (10b, s.v. עד מוצאי י"ט האחרון של חג).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Rashi there is commenting directly on Levi's position, which seems to be that even in Israel one may not eat *esrogim* on the eighth day. Although this is not the same as Abaye's position that one may not eat *esrogim* in the Diaspora on the eighth day, Rashi's interpretation applies to Abaye as well; since it might be possible to fulfill a *mitzva* with the *esrog* even during *bein hash'mashos* after the seventh day, מיגו דאתקצאי לבין השמשות אתקצאי לכולי יומא דשמיני. However, since we do not take the *arba minim* on the eighth day even in the diaspora, it cannot acquire an additional *muktza* status during *bein hash'mashos* after the eighth day that would carry into the ninth day.</sub>

Comment: a really basic question here, related to the paragraph following the word "Commentary".  When you/tosfos say muktza do you mean it's forbidden to touch the esrog? or it's forbidden to touch the succah?   for simplicity's sake, let's suppose we're in israel so there's no doubt re the day.    Muktza's about on shabbat, not touching things on shabbos that you can't use isn't it? and I suppose applies to yomtov days of a festival too.. and where does a meal fit into this?

Comment: @smu The esrog is muktza machmas mitzva, so on Shmini Atzeres you wouldn't be able to use if for its primary purpose (i.e. eating it). Tosafos discusses the decree upon esrog on account of sukka on 10b, in the context of the muktza edible fruits hanging as sukka decorations.

Comment: You refer to sukkos 10B. This link has it in English which I can read   http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Sukkah.pdf  but I don't see any discussion there about the fruits in the sukkah.  I guess it's only in the Tosfos on that page.  Since you refer to rashi and tosfos 10b in your answer, Are you able to translate or summarise the relevant tosfot on sukkos 10b  alongside the relevant hebrew?  http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=10b&format=text  (the hebrew can be copy/pasted)

Comment: I get the idea though, you sit in the sukkah in babylon, the fruits decorating the succah have a ritual purpose decorating the succah, the decorative fruits serve their ritual purpose throughout the day and can't be eaten. If somebody eats an esrog after ritual use(like resh lakish might 46B!) then, you say somebody may think to eat the fruit on that 8th day, and in babylon that's not allowed, so in babylon they decreed not to eat the esrog.

Comment: also, how did tosfos know what was decreed in babylon, if they were in france and germany?

Comment: @smu (1.) The mention of fruits is on the very end of the gemara on 10a running into the very beginning of 10b, and Tosafos discusses that gemara. Basically, he explains why מיגו דאתקצאי לבין השמשות does not apply to esrog but does apply to sukka, and he mentions incidentally why esrog is therefore forbidden anyway on the 8th in Babylonia (since he rejected מיגו דאתקצאי לבין השמשות as a possibility). (2.) In this context, Babylonia is a generic term referring to the Diaspora. Babylonia was the main center of Jewry in the Diaspora during the time of the gemara.

Comment: ok i'll just provide a translation to some of the hebrew you wrote.  אתרוג אפילו בשמיני אסורה (even the esrog is forbidden on the 8th day)     and there's a rule you wrote of  מיגו דאתקצאי לבין השמשות אתקצאי לכולי יומא דשמיני  (when it's set aside for twilight it's set aside for the whole of the 8th day)  {Note when the rule says set aside for twilight, it means used ritually at twilight}.  Does Rashi give a reason for thinking the Esrog is directly forbidden? and does he think it's direct from that rule?

Comment: Also, how do you know that when 46B tosfos says "for the sake of succah", it's  talking about succah decorations like the gemara near the end of 10A was?

Comment: Plus, in the diaspora, whatever sets aside the succah and its decorations, sets aside the esrog too. The fact that there's a doubt-sfak yom, and it might be succot. So why are they decreeing forbidden based on succah decorations, and not decreeing it forbidden based on the fact that it's succot. Or does Tosfot when it says "for the sake of succah" the first time(i.e. for israel), mean "succah decorations" and the second time(i.e. for diaspora) mean "sukkot"?

Comment: @smu (1.) Rashi doesn't provide an explicit reason, but the explanation fits with the flow and wording of the gemara. Abaye explains the reasoning of Rabbi Yochanan for distinguishing between sukka and esrog (i.e. that only sukka is muktza on the 8th in Israel) by saying that מיגו דאתקצאי applies to the former but not to the ladder. Then, the gemara immediately cites Levi's opinion that both are forbidden in Israel on the 8th. Apparently on this basis, Rashi infers that Levi holds that מיגו דאתקצאי applies to both.

Comment: @smu (2.) On consideration, Tosafos likely refers to the sukka itself as the basis for the decree about esrog (as opposed to sukka decorations); Tosafos elsewhere writes that the muktza status of the *s'chach* is biblical, which would better explain the distinction between the eighth and ninth days in Babylonia, since the decree on account of sukka would be a fence around a biblical prohibition. This also fits better with the wording of Tosafos, since it says אטו סוכה and not אטו נוי סוכה. In that case, the concern is that if you eat the esrog you may also treat the s'chach as permitted.

Comment: In English, what is the difference between אטו סוכה and     אטו נוי סוכה ?    Levi's ruling might not be based on R Yochanan's rule. It's hard to see how it is.  Also, I can see how we can get from schach being  muktza on the 7th, to with that rule, schach being muktza on the 8th as it's used at twilight. But I don't see how you get from schach being muktza on the 8th, to esrog being muktza on the 8th.  So if somebody eats the esrog, they might remove the schach, maybe but I don't see that reasoning employed. Levi just has his position,  no reason given. Rashi adopts Levi's position.

Comment: I don't see reason to think Rashi uses that rule(based on the  tosfot translations provided in this thread).  He just adopts Levi's position (like levi giving no reason either!).  And Tosfot while I don't know what "on account of sukkah" refers to, I can see why the esrog could be decreed forbidden to eat in bavel but allowed in israel. e.g. on account not of sukkah, but of -sukkot-.if it were "on account of a sukkah's -schach-" it'd have the same problem  I mentioned with sukkah decorations i.e. why not decree re esrog based on it being sfak sukkot rather than on schach or sukkah decorations!

Comment: I have an answer here.. regaerding Levi's position. Let me know what you think.  The soncino says twilight might be regarded as the beginning of one day or the end of the other day. In which case, The Esrog is forbidden to be eaten at twilight, and therefore, forbidden on the 8th day. Then Tosfos seems strange for rejecting Rashi and Levi. Also R Yochanan seems strange for not taking Levi's position. And it  still doesn't explain why Tosfot say esrog forbidden on account of succah - what is meant. And why not say on account of sukkot.

Comment: Note also though, if we examine Levi's position and the reason in the soncino, there may be lots of implications.. of other times when something is muktza on a day particularly at twilight, it'd have to be muktza for another day, so that doesn't much sense either as a reason.

Comment: @smu (1.) אטו סוכה means "on account of sukka" (not sukkos), while אטו נוי סוכה would mean "on account of sukka decorations". (2.) "The Esrog is forbidden to be eaten at twilight, and therefore, forbidden on the 8th day." That does seem to be Rashi's rationale, which Tosafos disputes on 10b (study that Tosafos for details). (3.) "R Yochanan seems strange for not taking Levi's position." To which explanation of Levi are you referring? According to Rashi, R' Yochanan is explicit in the gemara about why he disagrees with Levi. According to Tosafos... see the Tosafos (46b).

Comment: Where does it say אטו נוי סוכה ?    Do we have anything definitive yet on what ato succah is talking about?  and Do we really need to examine what Levi Rashi and R Yochanan say to decipher what it ato succah in tosfos is talking about?

Comment: I cant comment on all the sources as all I've got translated the entire talmud but not entire tosfos or entire rashi.The only tosfos I have translated is that provided here.So if in making your point u keep introducing new sources into the discussion that I haven't got translated,then it's difficult.So,if rashi,or tosfos provide objections or refutations to some of my points,then fine.But getting back to the point.What sources are required for u2 make ur case of what atoh succah is talking about?

Comment: r u able 2 at least quote the sources in hebrew, that make ur case. And can you say how certain you are that your interpretation of atoh succah is correct..  Is it very clear what it refers to, or is it extremely speculative?  if it's very speculative then there's probably no point.

Comment: thanks for your attempt, but since you  haven't been able to answer the queries to your answer, and you haven't picked any holes in my answer, I will accept my own answer.